# Scroll bar does not hide for single line?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a table in which a specific `<td>` will have dynamic text. It should scroll when multiple lines are present. So I used the `overflow:auto` property. But even when the content is not overflowed the scroll bar is visible. It is visible all of the time.

My PHP code is:

```
printf( '<table class="scroll-table">' );
printf( '<tr><td>..</td>');
printf( '<td ><div style="float: left"><strong>Comment:</strong></div> <div class="scroll">%s</div></td>',$info['comment'] );
```

CSS properties:

```
.scroll-table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.scroll-table td{
    width:33%;
    padding-right:4px;
}
.scroll{
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    width: 20em;
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: The PHP is completely irrelevant for this question, so instead of posting the PHP post the HTML that the PHP generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code in three browsers, here are the results

- Firefox 40.0.3 = ok
- Chrome 45.0.2454.85 = ok
- IE 11.0.9600.17905 = scrollbar

This is the inherent behavior of IE, however you can change `height: 1em;` to `height: 1.1em;` in your CSS and make the scrollbars go away in IE.

Another note: This makes reading the comments extremely difficult. You can only read one line at a time.

You can use `height: auto;` in your CSS for `.scroll` to make multi-line comments easier to read, but then the scrollbar comes back using IE (even if there is only one line). IE just doesn't play very nice. It is a coder's nightmare.

Also don't forget to close your tags as Fky said, but that had no affect on the scrollbar. Still, good advice.

Comment: Wow..its working with `height: 1em;`..Thank you Kuya..I also looking into the multiline..As per your suggestion,If we use `height:auto`,it will increase the row height.Since my table does not have table border,the unwanted space will not give good look in the page..Please let me know any way to do this.(Making readability as well as not increasing row size)

Comment: That's hard to say. I would need to see the html code for the page. Just guessing you might could use a div that would "float" and not move the rest of the page around. But that's only a guess without seeing your html.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line

```
printf( '<td ><div style="float: left"><strong>Comment:</strong></div> <div class="scroll">%s</div></td>',$info['comment'] );
```

by

```
printf( '<td ><div style="float: left"><strong>Comment:</strong></div> <div class="scroll">%s</div></td></tr></table>',$info['comment'] );
```

Check to close all tag you've got opened :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because 1em is only the text size, you have to set padding e.g. 0.125em and then the line size is 1.5em. Make sure you use box-sizing:border-box.